# Put tags under input form

Tags: html, css

I am having the following input form:

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-box {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.search-input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.image-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.image-info .icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}

.position-relative:hover .image-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="search-box">
    <form method="GET" action="" class="text-center search-box">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-9">
          <div class="search-input-group">
            <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search like on " value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="mt-1">
        <span class="badge bg-secondary tag" data-tag="Midjourney">Midjourney</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary tag" data-tag="ChatGPT">ChatGPT</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary tag" data-tag="Dalle2">Dalle2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to put the tags under the input field, like that:

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS code, you have to remove the `margin-bottom: 50px` rule for the `.search-box` class. This rule creates a space under the form.

Updated snippet :

```css
.header {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.search-box {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.search-input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 8px;
}

.image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.image-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.image-info .icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}

.position-relative:hover .image-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="search-box">
    <form method="GET" action="" class="text-center search-box">
      <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-9">
          <div class="search-input-group">
            <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search like on " value="">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="mt-1">
        <span class="badge bg-secondary tag" data-tag="Midjourney">Midjourney</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary tag" data-tag="ChatGPT">ChatGPT</span>
        <span class="badge bg-secondary tag" data-tag="Dalle2">Dalle2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```